# challenge in creating lobbies for online games with database decision

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite

Recently, I am trying to create lobbies for online games.  There are more than 1000 online users playing the games . Therefore, I should make lobbies compatible with this huge amount of online.
At first, I had tried MySQL database to store lobby's data and fetching it every 5 seconds. This exploded my server, although public users had no access to it .

Then I came up with storing data on text files. It was also a disaster, because of complexity of the work.

another option I am looking forward is SQLite.

Do you recommend this one , or you have better suggestion for creating lobbies of online games.

Project has been written with PHP.

Comment: I don't know what a game lobby is, or what it's doing, but MySQL should be able to handle the data storage of such a site if properly managed and paired with the right techniques. How do you know that MySQL was the culprit? Did you attempt to `EXPLAIN` your queries to optimize? Your approach to "storing and fetching data every 5 seconds" may be impacted by a number of different issues, including your code organization, the amount of data you're storing/fetching, server configuration, etc.

Comment: thanks @JaredFarrish , I tried my best on optimizing my codes but so many connections needed for refreshing the lobby. Do you think MySQL is capable of that huge data transfer?

Comment: Have you tried something like Prevayler?

Comment: You need to look into [performance profiling](http://xdebug.org/) to find where your bottlenecks are. This is a complex problem, with many different approaches (for instance, [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) was built for multi-concurrent connection-based applications, and can outperform Apache). You can also look into concurrency approaches like [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/) (as @Victor suggests), [memory caching](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php), [OpCode optimization](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), etc.

Answer (score 2):

1000 users doing a read every 5 seconds is 200 queries/s, which is not much at all for mysql - depending of course on the hardware you're running it one.
find out what your bottleneck really is - is most of the time really spent on the db connection? maybe you can speed things up even thru web server configuration.

caching doesn't seem feasible for this use case. but what about some sort of in-memory database? (if you expect the data to fit in memory)

shard the data, use master/slave replication - ie. throw more hardware at it; look into nosql if your data model is simple enough.